# padding using <mark> in css

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to properly use the padding feature in css with the following html where it is only padding the first word on the left-hand side.

the css I am using on that it now that is not working correctly is

```css
mark {
  background-color: #89ce40;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.89;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-content">
  <h1><strong><span><mark>COMPREHENSIVE IT </mark><mark> SERVICES YOU CAN TRUST</mark><mark></mark></span></strong></h1>
  <h2><mark><span>Let us help you develop an IT </span></mark><mark> Optimization Strategy and </mark><mark> Define your technological </mark><mark> priorities</mark></h2>
</div>
```

I've also tried calling the padding functions through `.slide-content{padding-left: 10px;}`

Is there any way I can separate through each the padding through each `<mark></mark>` section?

[image]

^ This is what it looks like when `mark{padding right: 8px; padding-left 20px}`
I am trying to get each line to be padded on the left like the first word of each element

I have been able to fix it for the right hand side padding by playing with mark more but on the left hand side it is still only the first word in each string that is being padded vs the beginning of each `<mark>`

It has just occured to me that the padding is being applied on the above line, I am sorry for my previously poor explanations of what I am trying to do.

Comment: In the snippet above there you can see the padding. What is your desired result? I cannot properly understand what you need

Comment: I will take a screenshot and edit my post to try and explain better, sorry :)

Comment: so basically if you run the code snippet above the 'L' in techological has no padding to the right of it and i am looking for a way to add padding to that :)

Comment: I understood it wrong, I'm sorry. The text has it's padding, check the image here -> https://imgur.com/a/iufR8so . If you check the behavior it's working fine. If you need to fit it in a container that has a fixed `width` you need to style it properly. But the `padding` is working fine in your case

Comment: Off topic: I recommend using "I.T." to avoid reading confusion. :)

Comment: its getting that padding from 'padding-right:' the padding left is only being applied to the first word in each string 'h1 & h2'

Comment: You need to change the spacing between the words then not mark all of them in one tag and set the props to it

Comment: Let me get this right... you need `5px` on left and `10px` on right at each word?

Comment: The mark element is an inline element and as such, the result you are getting is exactly what is supposed to happen.  I'm afraid the result you are after is not possible, unless you wrap each line in a separate element.

Comment: I'm willing to do that! did you have something specific in mind? @HaukurHaf

Comment: @sabbin not at each word but on the left and right of each <mark>

Comment: @jblaupunkt just to make sure, can you post a drawing which shows what result you are after, exactly?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1A8FKkH - The marks have padding as they should. On left and on right... so I cannot follow your issue

Comment: I updated my post to show that it is not working for me... Is there another html element that could help this? @Sabbin

Comment: can you post a image with the desired result? maybe it's easier to write it from scratch

Comment: The padding is leaking over from the top line onto the line above it, my desired result is that every line looks like the first <mark> in h1 and the first <mark> in h2

Comment: @Sabbin what element should I use differently building it this time? <br>?

Comment: `<br/>` is used to break line, it makes the text to jump on the next line.. you can use it if you need to separate the text on different lines

Comment: I am willing to make an image is there a site where I could do this easily? @Sabbin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188429/discussion-between-sabbin-and-jblaupunkt).

Comment: I posted my answer below on what worked for me to fix this issue, I appreciate all the help though @Sabbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [`<mark>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/mark) is an `inline` Element

[`inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) element dimensions are not faithfully set to intuitive lengths -- they "wrap" around the content. [`inline-block` and `block`](https://medium.com/@DaphneWatson/css-display-properties-block-inline-and-inline-block-how-to-tell-the-difference-7d3a1e6e3051)  elements will conform to the dimensions given (more or less. )Add `display:inline-block` or `block`.

### Demo

```css
mark {
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: #89ce40;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.89;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-content">
  <h1><strong><span><mark>COMPREHENSIVE IT </mark><mark> SERVICES YOU CAN TRUST</mark></span></strong></h1>
  <h2><mark><span>Let us help you develop an IT </span></mark><mark> Optimization Strategy and </mark><mark> Define your technological </mark><mark> priorities</mark></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<br>` fixed my problem above regarding the padding, thank you @Sabbin for helping out!

```
<h1 style="text-align: left;"><strong><mark>COMPREHENSIVE I.T. <br></mark><mark> SERVICES YOU CAN TRUST</mark><mark></mark></strong></h1>
    <h2 style="text-align: left;"><mark>Let us help you develop an I.T. <br></mark><mark> Optimization Strategy and <br></mark><mark> Define your technological<br></mark><mark> priorities</mark></h2>



mark {
background-color: #89ce40; 
color: white; 
opacity: 0.89;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<mark>` is by default inline element. So every `<mark>` block is rendered in one line and thus you don't see the padding in the subsequent rows. It is adding the padding, but at the end of the previous row.

You can address this issue in multiple ways.

One way would be to float:left all `<mark>` elements and add clear:both so they all go one below another.

```
mark {
   /*your code*/
   float:left;
   clear:both;
}
```

Other way would be to make the `<mark>` elements block elements, but they will take full width. The code would then be:

```
mark {
    /*your code*/
    display:block;
}
```

Using flex, you can achieve the same by using the following code:

```
mark {
    /*your code*/
    display: flex;
}
```

Choose what works best for you.